# What does the `l` option mean in GNU sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I have read the [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) manual for the `-l` command. There it says:

> ```
> -l
> --line-length=N
> ```
>
> Specify the default line-wrap length for the `l` command. A length of 0 (zero) means to never wrap long lines. If not specified, it is taken to be 70.

I don't know how this is useful. Can someone give me an example?

I think it like this,but it result:

```
[root@kvm ~]# echo 'abcdefg' | sed -l 3  -n '/a/p'
abcdefg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`sed` manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html):

> **Commands which accept address ranges**
>
> ...
>
> `l`      List out the current line in a ``visually unambiguous''
>   form.
>
> `l` *`width`*   List out the current line in a ``visually
>   unambiguous'' form,
>                 breaking it at width characters.  This is a GNU extension.

The **`-l`** `N`, **`--line-length=`***N* option allows to specify the desired line-wrap length for the '`l`' command (when the wrap-width argument is not explicitly provided in the sed script).

```
$ echo abcdefgh | sed -n 'l 5'
abcd\
efgh$
$ echo abcdefgh | sed -n -l 5 'l'
abcd\
efgh$
$ echo abcdefgh | sed -n -l 5 'l 3'
ab\
cd\
ef\
gh$
```

Comment: Using a capital 'L', the unambiguous markings for newline and eof are not added in, making it easier to format the text file to say 70 characters.  `sed -n -l 70 'L' `

Answer (score 4):

Why not try it and see?

```
$ echo 'abcdefg' | sed -l 3 'l'
ab\
cd\
ef\
g$
abcdefg

$ echo 'abcdefg' | sed -l 4 'l'
abc\
def\
g$
abcdefg
```

Comment: +1. It looks like the OP did try to try it, but missed the significance of the phrase "for the l command" in the documentation (due to not realizing that "command" and "option" are separate things in sed).

Comment: (s)he added that attempt to the question after I posted my answer. Previously the question ended at `Can someone give me an example?`.